# Modify real part and leaves imaginary part unchanged

Tags: complex

How can I flip the sign of the real part but not affect the imaginary part of a complex number:

`a+bi` => `-a + bi`

Example list:

```
list = {{-0.282095 + 0.282095 I, -0.27254 + 0.291336 I, 
-0.262018 + 0.300835 I, -0.250437 + 0.310542 I}}
```

expected:

```
{{0.282095 + 0.282095 I, 0.27254 + 0.291336 I, 
0.262018 + 0.300835 I, 0.250437 + 0.310542 I}}
```

So it's "similar" to conjugate but works on the real not imaginary.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
-Conjugate[list]

(* {{0.282095 + 0.282095 I, 0.27254 + 0.291336 I, 
     0.262018 + 0.300835 I, 0.250437 + 0.310542 I}} *)
```

Comment: This is not even a Mathematica but a Math answer. I like it

Answer (score 10):

```
list /. Complex[x_, y_] :> Complex[-x, y]
```

> {{0.282095 + 0.282095 I, 0.27254 + 0.291336 I, 0.262018 + 0.300835 I, 
>     0.250437 + 0.310542 I, 2, 3 I}}

Comment: This assumes that all entries are truly `Complex[_,_]`. But for a list `{{-0.282095 + 0.282095 I, -0.3445}}`, which also contains only complex numbers (although one of them happens to be purely real, and even have `Real` head), this won't work correctly.

Comment: Agreed. This solution is for complex numbers of the form a + b i that was asked in the question. To include real numbers it needs to be modified to `{Complex[x_,y_]:>Complex[-x,y], x_:>-x}`.

Comment: Actually this would also break for "complex" number like e.g. `1.234+0I`, which actually collapses to a `Real`

Answer (score 2):

```
f[z_] = -Re[z] + I Im[z]
f[list]

(* {{0.282095 + 0.282095 I, 0.27254 + 0.291336 I, 0.262018 + 0.300835 I, 0.250437 + 0.310542 I}} *)
```